# Copying a sheet within LibreOffice while keeping the references the same

Tags: libreoffice

I have two sheets: `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. `Sheet2` contains as `A1`: `=Sheet1.A1 + 2`. I want to save a copy of `Sheet2` as `Sheet3`. I want to have the same content in `Sheet3` as there is in `Sheet2` but automatically it sets `A1`: `=Sheet2.A1 + 2`.

Is there a way to create a copy this way?